# How do I rebuild a .jar file after removing classes in linux command line?

Tags: java, linux, exception, command

After removing a couple of classes from a .jar file  I get this error when attempting to run it:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

I was told that I had to rebuild the .jar file to fix this so that the path is correct.

So how can I do this from Linux command line?

The .jar file is a server program I am running on ubuntu server 12.04, specifically a minecraft server and the classes I have removed are mods.

edit: I literally dragged and dropped the two additional files into the .jar via WinRAR to start with, then deleted them afterwards, if this makes any difference?

Comment: You can't just remove .class files and expect things to still work :s That's like removing the Windows system32 folder to free up space.

Comment: You need to decompile all classes in the jar and find all references to the classes you removed. Then create a new jar.

Comment: So there isn't one file that defines all references of each class? I thought perhaps I only had to edit one file..

Comment: I litterally dragged and dropped the two addition files into the .jar via WinRAR to start with, then deleted them afterwards, if this makes any difference?

Comment: Minecraft could reference these jars in the registry or FS, so these entries need to be deleted. This could be the case: [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110114170350AAAEPP0).